# ordering columns in dataframe based on incomplete vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector based on col names which looks like

```
x <- c("C", "A", "T")
```

my dataframe looks like with rownames and colnames defined.

```
names    A    B    C    D    T
 Dan     1    0    1    0    1
 Joe     0    1    0    1    0
```

I want to order the dataframe so the columns in the vector appear first followed by columns not in the vector

```
names    C    A    T   B    D
Dan      1    1    1   0    0
Joe      0    0    0   1    1
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: you can do it using `setdiff()` and `c()` and `colnames()`

Comment: BTW, your vector `x` should use strings, so it should look like this: `x <- c("C", "A", "T")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will rearrange your data to set the columns specified in the vector `x` at the beginning, and the remaining columns in their original order afterwards.

```
x <- c("C", "A", "T")

mydata <- mydata[, c(x, setdiff(names(mydata), x))]
```

If the `names` column should stay at the first position and is not specified within `x`, use (Thanks @StevenBeaupré for pointing it out and providing the code):

```
mydata <- mydata[, c(names(mydata)[1], x, setdiff(names(mydata)[-1], x))]
```

Small data example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(names = c("Dan", "Joe"), A = c(1, 0), B = c(0,1), 
                     C = c(1, 0), D = c(0,1), T = c(1, 0))

> mydata
  names A B C D T
1   Dan 1 0 1 0 1
2   Joe 0 1 0 1 0

mydata <- mydata[, c(names(mydata)[1], x, setdiff(names(mydata)[-1], x))]

> mydata
  names C A T B D
1   Dan 1 1 1 0 0
2   Joe 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: You might want to exclude the first column to match OP's desired output: `df[c(names(df)[1], x, setdiff(names(df)[-1], x))]`

Comment: Thanks Leo and Steven. I have tried this command but get the following error `error in mydata[, c(names(mydata)[1], x, setdiff(names(mydata)[-1]  : undefined columns selected` is this because row1 are my colnames?

Comment: The error was due to a tailing blank in my x vector.